# Js.erb VS Button_tag - doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have this code in my js.erb file:

```
m = "<%= button_tag 'Update', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>"
$('#yield').prepend(m)
```

And it doesn't work at all, even doesn't render simple text.
The problem is in the button_tag, because other code works well, for example:

```
<%= 'hello world'%>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape it:

```
m = "<%= escape_javascript(button_tag 'Update', :class => 'btn btn-success') %>"
```

Or you can use the `j` shortcut:

```
m = "<%=j button_tag 'Update', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>"
```